# How can i call a method in a hiperlink?

Tags: html, vue.js

I need to call this method in vue.js file:

```
par() {
    this.jsontocsv++
}
```

but i'm triying to call whith a  but i dont know how i can

```
<li> <a v-on:click="par" href="#"> Example 1</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you share more codes e.g. `methods: { par() { ... }}`?

Comment: Put a `console.log('Test')` underneath `this.jsontocvs++` to see if its the method which isn't firing, or the code just isn't doing what you want

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the method using `()`:

```
<li> <a v-on:click="par()" href="#"> Example 1</a></li>
```